# how to install sqoop in cygwin with windows7?

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, sqoop

I've already installed cygwin in windows7. Now I plan to add sqoop to cygwin for hadoop but I'm not getting it right...

Can anybody please suggest me the correct way for doing so, or a link detailing it?

Comment: It sounds like you're pretty far off base here - I don't really understand the phrase "sqoop to cygwin for hadoop". If you have data on the Windows machine that you want to Sqoop into a Hadoop cluster, you need to execute the Sqoop command from an edge node of the Hadoop cluster, not from the Windows machine.

Comment: i mean how to start sqoop with hadoop.....in windows environment....i have seen some videos every where they used to work on ubento only thats why i asked...

Answer (score 0):

Please don't make yourself complicated.

 I can only recommend running sqoop on hadoop in a linux virtual machine or native linux. 
Although successfully running hadoop 0.20.0 on windows xp+cygwin and windows7+cygwin, I once tried setting up a newer version of hadoop on windows7, but failed miserably due to errors in hadoop. 

 I have wasted days and weeks on this.

So my advice: run hadoop on linux if you can, you'll avoid a serious amount of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reconsider installing Hadoop on Windows, it is not very easy to do it and it is probably more trouble than it is worth, although I believe others have done it.

Anyway there are several other options you could consider with regards to hadoop, first there's two companies I know of that provide free VM's and one of them has worked with Microsoft to try and integrate Hadoop into Windows. Anyway, these are the links:

http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-4.html

http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/#install

Otherwise you can try your luck with the default apache installation, though I warn you, if you're new to linux or don't like to spend a lot of time changing configuration files, going this way is not the best. I did my installation this way, and you have to modify a lot of files, plus anything extra like Hive, Sqoop, HBase, etc. needs to be installed separately and configured as well.